# Connecting Usb bluetooth Dongle with BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

I am in a confusion with the Usb Bluetooth Dongle. I have one from ICIDU V4.0 . I wrote a program in C# using 32feet library to detect the Bluetooth devices in the surrounding as a result i can get all the devices listed (like Smart phones) except one which is BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). I also tried changing the Usb Bluetooth Dongle and then used the one from the TRUST but couldn't succeed :(

Do i need to have a especial type of a Usb Bluetooth Dongle to connect with BLE or is it simply that 32feet.net library doesn't support BLE?

If it's the problem with the Usb Dongle then can anyone suggest me a Dongle which is easily available in the market :) and if its the problem with the 32feet.net library then which one am i suppose to use ??

Any help and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a dongle that supports Bluetooth 4.0 and you have to do a different type of "scan" to detect BLE devices.  A regular bluetooth scan will only detect regular bluetooth, you have to do a LE scan to detect BLE devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tim, So this means i don't need to buy a new Bluetooth dongle? 
Can you tell me how can i scan the Low Energy Bluetooth in my code, what are the things i have to implement? is there any any available samples or links referring to this? Please give me some suggestions i am really in need of this.

Comment: unfortunately I have no experience with C#...  I just know in Linux Bluez there are completely separate calls for BLE scanning and regular Bluetooth scanning.  I also know they really are very different so I imagine most systems would also have them separate.  First step is to confirm you have a 4.0 dongle.  Then see if your library actually supports 4.0 standards such as BLE.  A quick search on that website seems to indicate that it doesn't. (usually if they don't mention it, it means they don't support it)

Comment: thanks you tim for your information, i will look around in internet. Hopefully will find some information.